# Which is better way to communicate with database in Android and Why?

Tags: android

As of now , I know 2 methods to interact with database ,
using openOrCreateDatabase() or extending SQLiteOpenHelper class !
Which is better to use and why ?

Answer (score 2):

I can remember using SQLiteOpenHelper class in Google's beginner tutorial [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html)
So this seems to be the "recommended" way to the database..
Some opinions: [Link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4d7d533a70ee0fca), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901057/problem-in-creating-a-database-in-sqlite-in-android)
Also take a look at the api to compare eachother:
[SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), [openOrCreateDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29)

Answer (score 1):

I've used `openOrCreateDatabase()` method because it seems simple and easy to me.

Comment: I too was thinking that way ! , but there should be some reason why Android is providing 2 ways !